# Getting an error with a period should be between alias name and period?

Tags: sql, teradata

I totally thought I was over the SQL hump but still getting issues! So my code is here for example:

```
create volatile table final_pull as ( 
Select Distinct 
a.id

a.id_2

a.id_3

b.kd

b.kd_1

From table1 as A
Left Join table2 as B
 

from 
) with data on commit preserve rows
```

(I'm not on my work computer so I'm blanking on the actual ending for this lol)

My apologies! I definitely wrote this too late and didn't even realized till I got the comments. My mistake. So the issue was that I was getting an error saying that I needed a ( between A and .

Thank you!

Comment: You need to show your actual code and error message. Based on your dummy code there's no SELECT and missing commas :-)

Comment: This code just makes no sense.  There are no types for the columns.  The column names contain non-conforming characters.  And there might be other problems as well.

Comment: Missing commas?